# CNTK reader for base64 encoded images in Python

Tags: cntk

I'm migrating training and evaluation configurations for CNTK from Brainscript over to Python. Because our training data is created in a map/reduce framework, I'm storing images and labels in a huge text file that contains the base64 encoded image as one of its columns. That all worked fine, but I still have not found a way of doing the equivalent in Python.

My CNTK.exe configuration is similar to [this example configuration](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/2ef2b7e8e39071a28c74672d99854ccefbac0501/Tests/EndToEndTests/Image/Base64Write/EvalNetOnImages.cntk):

```
deserializers = ({
        type = "Base64ImageDeserializer" ; module = "ImageReader"
        file = "myFile.tsv"
...
```

All Python examples (for example [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/BrainScript-and-Python---Understanding-and-Extending-Readers#configuring-a-reader-minibatch-source-in-python)) use the `ImageDeserializer`, which reads from images that are individual files. I have not found anything that sounds like a base64 image deserializer in the Python code of `cntk.io`.

How can I use base64 encoded images in CNTK via Python?

A related ask: The Brainscript `Base64ImageDeserializer` accepts files that contain a sequence ID in the first column, which is critical for us to identify individual examples at test time. How can I use that in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Base64 deserializer support for Python was merged to master. For sample usage please see /bindings/python/cntk/io/tests/io_tests.py test_base64_image_deserializer.

Regarding getting labels - currently there is no easy way, you can compose CNTKTextFormat that will contain the ids. But this is cumbersome, we are discussing to make this easier.